# Ruby: How to include outside module in Rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, module

I have 2 projects, a "common code" project that i have made into a big module that pulls in other modules like so:

Here is the folder structure of "my-common-project":

- **my-common-project**

  - **common**

    - file_utils.rb
    - rest-client.rb
    - other ruby files with modules...
  - common.rb
  - Gemfile
  - etc...

## common.rb

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require_relative './common/file-utils.rb'
require_relative './common/rest_client.rb'
...

module Common
  include FileUtils
  include RestClient
  # include other modules here...
```

## file_utils.rb

```
module Common
  module FileUtils

    def open_file(file_name)
      dir = File.expand_path('') << '/lib'
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)
      File.open(File.expand_path('') << "/lib/#{file_name}", 'w')
    end
  end
end
```

I also have an Rspec project where i am doing a test:

- **my-rspec-project**

  - **spec**

    - my_test_spec.rb
    - spec_helper.rb
    - **lib**

      - my_class.rb
  - .rspec
  - Gemfile
  - etc...

## spec_helper.rb

```
require 'bundler'
require 'csv'
require_relative './lib/fp_relationship_api'
require_relative './../../../../../RubyProjects/mksta-common/common'

Bundler.require

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include Common
  ...
end
```

## my_class.rb

```
require "#{File.expand_path('') << '/spec_helper'}"

class MyClass

include Common

  @error_file = open_file('error_file.txt')
  ...
end
```

I get the error:

> undefined method `open_file' for MyClass:Class (NoMethodError)

Can anyone see what went wrong?

Comment: Where is `open_file`defined ?

Comment: @BernardK, open_file is defined in a class in another file within the common project. I will update the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have seen the problem immediately, but didn't. You see the difference between :

```
lib/my_class.rb:9:in `<class:MyClass>': undefined method `open_file' for MyClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

when `open_file` appears in the body of MyClass, and :

```
lib/my_class.rb:16:in `m': undefined method `open_file' for #<MyClass:0x007fbb0d10cc30> (NoMethodError)
```

if I put it in a `def` :

```
def m
    @error_file = open_file('error_file.txt')
```

In the first case, you are in the body of `MyClass`, where `open_file` is not defined. In the second case, I had removed the `include Common`.

To do my research, I've defined the minimum necessary to reproduce the error.
File `.../lib/file_utils.rb`, same as yours.

File `.../lib/common.rb` :

```
require_relative 'file_utils'

module Common
    puts "Common instance methods before include : #{instance_methods(true).sort}"
    include FileUtils
    puts "Common instance methods after  include : #{instance_methods(true).sort}"

    puts "Common class methods before extend : #{singleton_methods(true).sort}"
    extend FileUtils
    puts "Common class methods after  extend : #{singleton_methods(true).sort}"
end
```

File `.../lib/my_class.rb` :

```
require_relative 'common'

class MyClass
#    puts "MyClass methods before include : #{instance_methods(true).sort}"
    include Common
#    puts "MyClass methods after  include : #{instance_methods(true).sort}"

    puts "self=#{self}"
    puts "MyClass class methods before extend : #{singleton_methods(true).sort}"
    extend Common
    puts "MyClass class methods after  extend : #{singleton_methods(true).sort}"
    @error_file = open_file('error_file.txt')
    puts "in MyClass error_file=#{@error_file}"

    def m
        @error_file = open_file('error_file.txt')
        puts "in m error_file=#{@error_file}"
    end
end

MyClass.new.m
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w lib/my_class.rb 
Common instance methods before include : []
Common instance methods after  include : [:open_file]
Common class methods before extend : []
Common class methods after  extend : [:open_file]
self=MyClass
MyClass class methods before extend : []
MyClass class methods after  extend : [:open_file]
in MyClass error_file=#<File:0x007ff2621fcdc0>
in m error_file=#<File:0x007ff2621fc938>
```

**Explanation**

Due to the way you use `@error_file = open_file('error_file.txt')`, you are in the body of `MyClass`, which is executed only when the interpreter reads the class definition. When a method like `open_file` is used without a receiver, it is sent to the implicit receiver `self`, which is `MyClass`. But as it is defined, `open_file` is not a class method, it is an instance method.

If you need a class method (more exactly a singleton method), you have to define it as

```
def self.open_file(file_name)
```

or use `extend <module>`.

Comment: I ended up using `extend Common` to get the `open_file` method to work, like you described. The code now runs successfully. Thank you for the help. I may also need to use `include Common` though, due to using module instance methods within a def method in _my_class.rb_. Or i could change the instance methods to `def self.my_method` correct?

Comment: @AustinL No, if you change the instance methods to `def self.my_method`, it becomes a singleton (class) method, and will no longer be available as instance method. The best is `include` followed by `extend`.

Comment: Sounds good, I will go ahead and use both `include Common` and `extend Common`. Thank you